# OAuth2 consent page doesn't show scopes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm reading the book Spring in action 6 and authentication server doesn't work correctly. I've tried to make custom server or copy the one from the internet but it didn't help

Link: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=taco-admin-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-admin-client&-scope=writeIngredients+deleteIngredients

[That's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBGdL.png)

My bean:

```
@Bean
  public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(
          PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient =
      RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .clientId("taco-admin-client")
        .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(
                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
        .redirectUri(
            "http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-admin-client")
        .scope("writeIngredients")
        .scope("deleteIngredients")
        .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
        .clientSettings(
            clientSettings -> clientSettings.requireUserConsent(true))
        .build();
    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
  }
```

[That's how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDO4Q.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what was happening in my case was that the url was wrong,it had an extra dash behind the "scope=writeIngredients+deleteIngredients",so it wasn´t displaying the scopes.
the correct url would be:
http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=taco-admin-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-admin-client&scope=writeIngredients+deleteIngredients

Comment: I also faced the same issue while trying the same URL. Your comment saved a lot of time.

Comment: were you able to get retrieve the access token using curl command mentioned in the article ? 

I am getting invalid client as JSON response.